# Elasticsearch Python Response to CSV or JSON

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, elasticsearch

I'm new in Python and elasticsearch and have been struggle for couple days.

I have sample visualize table on elastic:
[image]

With request from elastic, I try to get data in Python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch ("access_to_elastic", timeout=30)

res = es.search(index= "kibana_sample_data_flights", body=
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
    "date_histogram": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "calendar_interval": "1h",
    "time_zone": "Asia/Bangkok",
    "min_doc_count": 1
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DestCountry",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "4": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Carrier",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "5": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "DestCountry",
                "order": {
                  "_count": "desc"
                },
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "6": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "FlightDelay",
                    "order": {
                      "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    "size": 100000
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
 "size": 0,
 "fields": [
 {
   "field": "timestamp",
   "format": "date_time"
 }],
 "script_fields": {},
 "stored_fields": ["*"],
 "runtime_mappings": {
 "hour_of_day": {
  "type": "long",
  "script": {
    "source": "emit(doc['timestamp'].value.getHour());"
   }
 }},
 "_source": {
 "excludes": []
 },
 "query": {
 "bool": {
  "must": [],
  "filter": [
    {
      "range": {
        "timestamp": {
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
          "gte": "2022-07-26T05:59:12.406Z",
          "lte": "2022-07-28T05:59:12.406Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "should": [],
  "must_not": []
  }
 }
})
```

The out put from those scripts:
[image]

***My question, is there any ways or document or anything else to make the output become more readable JSON, csv or dataframe?***

Thank you

Comment: `json.dumps(res, indent=4)` will do the trick. ES returns a size-efficient JSON object, and the indent in the dump() makes it more readable. Both are valid JSONs though...

Comment: @EdoAkse i tried, but got response: TypeError: Object of type 'ObjectApiResponse' is not JSON serializable. Any clue?

Comment: try `res.to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Same struggle here, in the end following worked for me:

```
print(json.dumps(res.body, indent=2))
```

Used Elasticsearch 8.5.3 and python libraries {elasticsearch==8.6.2, elastic-transport==8.4.0}.

ObjectApiResponse has a member attribute 'body' which is a dict.
Calling to_dict() on the ObjectApiResponse as was suggested does not work.